# Multiple insertion in mysql database, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to insert multiple record at the same time in the database and for that here is my sql instruction :

```
insert into tabo (fee,doo,ple,idur) values (?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?) ON duplicate key update tabo.doo=values(doo),tabo.fee=values(fee);
```

Whe I am executing it, it is bringing this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?) ON duplicate key update
>   tabo.doo=values(doo),tabo.fee=values(fee);

I am not able to know where exactly I have an error. I need help to know what is wrong with my query.

Here is my table tabo structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tabo (
fee varchar(100),
doo time,
ple time,
idu int(11),
PRIMARY KEY(idu,fee)
) engine=innodb;
```

I am using nodejs but even in mysql the query is not running and the package(module) I am using is mysqljs/mysql :

Here is my code:

```
connection.query('insert into tabo (fee,doo,ple,idur) values (?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?) ON duplicate key update tabo.doo=values(doo),tabo.fee=values(fee)' ,['Good','12:00','14:00','Bad','18:00','20:00','best','02:00','04:00','worst','06:00','08:00'], function (error, results, fields) {
if(error){
console.log(error);
}else{
console.log("success");
}
}
```

Comment: `ON duplicate key update doo=values(doo),fee=values(fee)` No table name (tabo) needed in clumn names

Comment: Did you bind any values to this or did you just slam it in as-is?

Comment: How do you run this statement, prepare/execute?

Comment: @NigelRen I am using nodejs but even in mysql the query is not running and the package(module) I am using is mysqljs/mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To insert ? in the mysql database, it has to be passed as a string "?" or '?' otherwise it generates error.
2. Since ? is used in the code as placeholder all of them should have a value in the second parameter of connection.query. So in the code :

   connection.query('insert into tabo (fee,doo,ple,idur) values (?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?) ON duplicate key update tabo.doo=values(doo),tabo.fee=values(fee)' ,['Good','12:00','14:00','Bad','18:00','20:00','best','02:00','04:00','worst','06:00','08:00'], function (error, results, fields) {
   if(error){
   console.log(error);
   }else{
   console.log("success");
   }
   }

There are 4 more values which are missing in that array meaning this array must have 16 values(elements) each will replace one ?.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no need for table name to update
2. Using values while update can cause error

Try this

```
insert into tabo (fee,doo,ple,idur) values (?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?) ON duplicate key update doo=doo1,fee=fee1;
```

Comment: it is not working , I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Well we could be more helpful if we get more details about the table and the values you tried to insert

Comment: I've given more details.